# Band-pass filter doubles the frequency

Tags: filters, frequency-spectrum, convolution, bandpass

I ran into a strange bug while implementing a complex band-pass filter. The filter design process is based on the windowing method and seems to be working well, but when i apply the coefs of the filter on my time domain input samples and perform DFFT the carrier frequency is doubled. I can´t really figure out why is this happening but my guess is that i'm doing something bad during the convolution. The first plot shows the magnitude response of the complex band pass filter. The second plot shows FFT of my input 5kHz carrier signal, the third one shows the same data but with BP filter applied. Everything is happening in the complex plain.

[image: complex band pass filter]

[image: No filter applied - 5kHz carrier] 
[image: Band-pass filter applied on the same 5kHz carrier input]

Comment: You must describe exactly what you're doing, otherwise there is no way for us to figure out what's happening. You could also plot the frequency response of the filter.

Comment: Firstly i compute the filter coefs using firdes class from GNU radio, see: https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/222e0003f9797a1b92d64855bd2b93f0d9099f93/gr-filter/lib/firdes.cc

Comment: Compute the FFT of the (zero-padded) filter coefficients and include the plot in your question.

Comment: BTW, I don't think that the filter coeffs are the problem but let's start at the beginning ...

Comment: I have a low rep so can't post more than 2 images at the moment. FFT of coefs is here http://i.stack.imgur.com/7huYn.jpg

Comment: I've added the plot. How do you do the convolution/filtering?

Comment: Here is my class which does the convolution part:
http://pastebin.com/PdvHxBEw

Comment: Have you tested your convolution routine? If so, how? I'm almost sure there's an error in there.

Comment: thanks a lot
its working with samp_rate/2 butr the flow graph it is showing is very slow
means it is perating in very slow mode
should i increase the sampling rate or i should make the transition width smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the origin of the problem while double checking the whole iplementation of my application. I added a method for reading a single input sample from binary file few weeks ago, but I somehow messed up the size of the buffer which I use. It has to be 8-byte long (room for 2 floats) representing real and imaginary part of the sample, but I used 16 bytes instead. Really stupid mistake! Thanks for your hepl, I appriciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You complex multiplication code inputs 2 samples for every output sample.  That will act as a frequency doubler.

Answer (score 0):

what's your sample frequency, fm? did you apply Nyquist theorem? You may need to do fm/2=fe and then transform the pass band, Wp, and the band eliminated, Ws, into Wp/fe and Ws/fe.

Comment: Sampling freq is 32kHz for this example, so the Nyquist theorem is respected

Comment: this is a simple Matlab example without windowing that may help you to check your method: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55822-low-pass-filtering